# Is there a away to override a shell's non-interactive state?

Tags: shell

A big company, jealous guardian of their highly customized Unix flavor, is restricting code-signing to interactive shells. We, however, would like our gitlab-runner to sign software products as part of our highly automatized continuous delivery process. Is there a way to override such patronizing restriction by tweaking a non-interactive shell so that it appears interactive to subordinate software?

Comment: If the Big Company has a Policy "restricting code-signing to interactive shells", and you manage to subvert it, you find yourself in legal trouble.

Comment: @waltinator - Big Company has no means to detect whether it was me, my employee, a bonobo, or a script that accepted their terms and conditions by typing "ok", "I accept", "Yes I sell you my sould". Nor will Big Company care, as long as I respect the terms and conditions accepted by me or my delegate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`expect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html). It is designed specifically to automate tasks over interactive stream.

Comment: If one would rather avoid working in TCL, other languages ought to have libraries that work just as well. For example, there's [python's "pexpect" library](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ruby's "expect" library](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/exts/pty/IO.html).